# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"error":"popup_closed_by_user"}

Tags: angular, authentication, ionic-framework, google-signin

I am trying to use Google login with the ionic app using angular 11. but I am keep receiving the error Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"error":"popup_closed_by_user"}

Also in the warnings, I am receiving "You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that will soon be deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead; existing clients must also migrate before these libraries are deprecated. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information."

I am also using angularx-social-login plugin.

let me know if anything else is required. need help.

Comment: Have you tried this?  https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login/issues/504#issuecomment-1142726408

Comment: Not yet .. let me try this.

Comment: it seems to be working but it is temporary fix or a permanent one?

Comment: Not sure..need to track issue continuously or I guess need to use updated or latest version of that lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have encountered this issue and was using '@abacritt/angularx-social-login' for social media login. This issue happens for all the newly created Google Client IDs. This can be resolved by adding 'plugin_name' in the provider if you are using Angular application.

In app.module.ts, create an object which holds the 'plugin_name'.

```
const googleLoginOptions = {
  scope: 'profile email',
  plugin_name:'login' //you can use any name here
};
```

And in  providers, pass the 'googleLoginOptions' object along with the google client ID.

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
    AppComponent
    ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SocialLoginModule
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [
        {
          provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
          useValue: {
            autoLogin: false,
            providers: [
              {
                id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
                  'YOUR GOOGLE CLIENT_ID', 
                   googleLoginOptions
                )
              }
            ],
            onError: (err) => {
              console.error(err);
            }
          } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
        }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Now, clear the browser cache and it should be working.
For the changes in app.component.ts you may refer to [@abacritt/angularx-social-login- documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abacritt/angularx-social-login)

This solution worked for me. Hope this helps.